# When l set the imeOptions as "flagNoExtractUi", it met a issue that the Softkeyboard keep invalid when in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, imeoptions

When set some language like Japanese, set the Edittext imeOptions as "flagNoExtractUi". In Portrait mode, the soft keyboard is normal, but when in landscape mode, the soft keyboard invalid.

When l changed the imeOptions as actionDone or actionNext, the soft keyboard are normal in any mode but the edittext field are full screen. So is there anything good solution about this? 
Thanks, best your regards!